# Kmeans clustering - Why do my clusters look like this?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, k-means

I am trying to understand why my clusters are not in groups and are color coordinated and laid out like this?

[image: my c]

Comment: How many columns of data do you have?  You are only plotting the first 2.

Comment: As I believe @James is hinting at is that KMeans is working just fine, but you are only looking at a 2D slice of the data. KMeans will take the entire dataset into consideration to create the Voronoi tessellation.

Comment: Oh OK! I see it now. Thank you!